# How to build Visual Studio .csproj as Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mono

**I`m using Visual Studio 2022.**

### The goal

Run Console application (.NET Framework) - on Mono (without Unity or other tools).

#### Console Application code:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    private static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mono!"); // Should be outputted 'Mono!' in console
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something other!");
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

#### Console Application .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

### My attempts:

[MonoHelper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dresel.MonoHelper) extension which is available only on super old versions of Visual Studio and probably deprecated because there`s no support.

`Mono msbuild`
Getting error after executing this line in `cmd`:
C:\Program Files\Mono>msbuild "path_to_project_here.csproj" -p:Configuration=Release

```
"path_to_project_here.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
  path_to_project_here.csproj : error MSB4237: The SDK resolver type "Dot
NetMSBuildSdkResolver" failed to load. The type initializer for 'Microsoft.DotNet.DotNetSdkResolver.VSSettings' threw a
n exception.
```

[xbuild](https://www.mono-project.com/archived/xbuild/) which is deprecated also, instead used `Mono msbuild`

Probably I wont be use `MonoDevelop` for such things, there`s should be easy way.

Answer (score 1):

It gives you not much benefit to convert .NET Framework only projects to the SDK style, as that adds up build time dependency on .NET Core SDK (you didn't install).

> Create a pure .NET Core console app (with `dotnet new console`) please, as that's recommended for cross platform scenarios.

Please install .NET Core SDK (.NET 6 or 7) and then use `dotnet build` to compile such projects. Then .NET CLI uses .NET Framework reference assemblies to build the executable and you can use `mono executable_name.exe` to run it on Linux. But note that if your console application uses any Windows only API/dependencies.

> MonoDevelop is totally irrelevant here.

> Both Mono and MonoDevelop are going away. .NET Core is the future.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I appreciate that. If I could I would be use .NET Core, but Im using frameworks which doesnt allows me to do that, as well In this topic as well as in this case - this is Unity, and other frameworks which allows me to use Game APIs.

Comment: @sunnamed If a framework does not support .NET Core today, it might be dying and you should stay away from it as soon as you can and migrate to alternatives. Unity as well as other game frameworks are either moving to .NET Core or already moved. Unity is almost a different things as it uses IL2CPP, https://blog.unity.com/technology/unity-and-net-whats-next

Answer (score 0):

0. [Install Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/) (select there your `OS`)

Build your application via Visual Studio as standard build then open `cmd` and cd into path where is `Mono` located, in my case this is (`Windows` `OS`) after that - run this builded app.

`C:\Program Files\Mono>` as x64;

for x86 `Mono` located here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono>` (path where is mono located)

1. Simply write `cd C:\Program Files\Mono>`
2. mono "path_to_the_compiled_executable_in_VS.exe" (executable should have entry point, console app will be great in such case)